# BCP command insert text file to SQL table

Tags: sql, bcp

I am trying to import into SQL a text file using this BCP command:

> bcp test.dbo.bcp2 in C:\Test\test.txt -c -t -SSQServer -U user -P
>   test1 -t \t -r\n -e C:\Test\error.txt

The text.txt file has \t as column delimiter and \n as row delimiter.

The error received is Unexpected EOF.

I can confirm that the SQL table has the right table definition so there should not be any conversion errors.

Comment: does any of the text fields contain commas of newline characters? That can cause your problem

Answer (score 0):

i think no need to put any delimiter  have text which is well arranged example if you have data in the excel copy and paste it in the text file and run the command

BCP tablename  in c:\test.txt -S server name -Uuserid -Ppassword -c